Trash or Recycle Old Halogen Under Cabinet Light Fixtures
I have these Westek lights that I replaced. I'd rather not trash them, but I'm not really sure they're recyclable. Or, maybe it's one of those things where I'd have to go through the hassle of taking some parts off that goes in the trash? I'd add more pictures, but it claims the file's too big. I'll try to add more at a later time.


This is the general problem of e-waste.
I installed a new inkjet printer for a customer last week. The old one had a small broken part, probably fixable. But the ink cost so much that over the course of the next year or so the new printer will likely pay for itself in ink savings. So was there any point in saving the printer as a "backup"? No, it would have to be fixed first, and likely never get used anyway. Was there any point in fixing it and giving it away? No, because the recipient would have to pay a fortune in ink costs. So into the trash it goes.
Parts of this light fixture, just like parts of a printer or computer or monitor or whatever, are likely recyclable. Steel or aluminum cases, copper wires and sometimes other parts are recyclable. But the effort to do so is significant. My electrician was able to salvage scrap metal from my old fuse boxes, but the "guts" went into the trash. For smaller and more complex devices such as many (not all) light fixtures, it just isn't practical, at least in the US and similar places, to separate out the recyclable stuff in an economical way. Even some things that are nominally recyclable without much manual labor, such as paper or glass (i.e., no electronic parts glued together, etc.), are often not truly economical to recycle but are recycled anyway for the good of the environment.
But when it comes to the complex-yet-small stuff, toss it. If your local jurisdiction has "e-waste collection", either as a periodic special collection event or as a part of the local solid waste transfer station (a.k.a., landfill) then you can save it for that, though I wouldn't count on it truly being recycled in the end.
The other way to recycle is to re-use. If you have a recent and functional LED light fixture and you don't like the style, give it away and someone will actually use it. But halogen? Those use a lot of energy relative to the light produced, so hardly anyone is going to want it because the cost of energy will, over a short period of time, outweigh any savings from getting a free light fixture.
